# Selection Sort without collections.sort in ArrayList

Tags: java, selection-sort

So, why won't this code work it is returning the original list always (I haven't put the return statement, but can someone determine why the logic behind my selection sort algorithm is not working). Any help would be gladly appreciated!

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class ArrayListDemo {
    public static void main(String [] args) {
        ArrayList <String> list = new ArrayList <String> (15);
        list.add("Wilson");
        list.add("Annans");
        list.add("Manning");
        list.add("Branday");
        list.add("Smittens");
        list.add(2, "Goddard Fey");
        list.set((list.size()) - 1, "Brand Brandon");
        list.add("Brand Boarders");
        selectionSort(list);
    }
    static void selectionSort(ArrayList<String> a) {
         int smallindex;
         for(int i = 0; i < a.size(); i++) {
              smallindex = i; // set first element as smallest
              for(int j = i + 1; j < a.size(); j++) { // find smallest
                   if (a.get(j).compareTo(a.get(smallindex)) > 0) {
                       swap(a, i, j);
                   }

              }
         }
    }

    static void swap(ArrayList<String> a, int index1, int index2) {
         String i_string = a.get(index1);
         String j_string = a.get(index2);
         String temp = i_string;
         i_string = j_string;
         j_string = temp;
    } 
}
```

Comment: Your `swap` method does not modify the `ArrayList` a anywhere. You need something like `a.set(index1, i_string)` etc.

Comment: Yes, you are creating new variables holding references, not values and then you are reassigning references without modifing the values.

you would have to go with a.set(index1, ...)

Answer (score 1):

Your `swap(ArrayList<String> a, int index1, int index2)` method creates local variables - `i_string` and `j_string` - and then swaps them. This has no impact on the contents of the input `List` `a`.

To change the value of the `i`'th element of the `List` `a` you must call `a.set(i,newValue)`.

You can either implement the swap method yourself, or use the existing `Collections.swap`:

```
static void selectionSort(ArrayList<String> a) {
    int smallindex;
    for(int i = 0; i < a.size(); i++) {
        smallindex = i; // set first element as smallest
        for(int j = i + 1; j < a.size(); j++) { // find smallest
            if (a.get(j).compareTo(a.get(smallindex)) > 0) {
                Collections.swap(a, i, j);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

If you wish to learn how to implement `swap` correctly, you can take a look at the JDK implementation:

```
public static void swap(List<?> list, int i, int j) {
    final List l = list;
    l.set(i, l.set(j, l.get(i)));
}
```

As you can see, this method sets the value returned by `l.set(j, l.get(i))` to be  the new `i`'th element of the `List`. `l.set(j, l.get(i))` sets the value `l.get(i)` as the new `j`'th element of the `List` and returns the previous `j`'th element. Therefore the new `i`'th element of the `List` becomes the previous `j`'th element.

Comment: Side question: Why did they assign `list` to a final variable before swaping elements?

Comment: @Gabriel well, `list.set(i, list.set(j, list.get(i)));` doesn't pass compilation due to the type of `list` being `List<?>`. Of course, they could have defined the method as `public static <T> void swap(List<T> list, int i, int j)`, and then `list.set(i, list.set(j, list.get(i)));` would have worked. I'm not sure why they didn't do that. Perhaps the reason was backwards compatibility (this method was introduced before generics were added to Java).